# some errata? or Not in Calculus book?

Tags: calculus, simpsons-rule

I think I found some errata in the book James Stewart Calculus 8th EarlyTran... (Still found not corrected in 9th also).

Chapter 7.7 (Approximate Integration)

Page 522, about Simpson's Rule:

[image]

At the middle of the page below the table, I think the integrand A(x) should be replaced to D(x) to estimate the integral using function D(x) by using Simpson's Rule.

Is this just a Typo(errata) or Am I wrong??

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in a comment, you are right; this is an error in the book.